# Cannot find gobind executable file

Tags: android, go

I'm trying to produce aar file by run command gomobile bind as per below :

> gomobile bind -target=android golang.org/x/mobile/example/bind/hello

But always, getting error like below :

> gomobile: gobind -lang=go,java -outdir=/var/folders/s_/yzvdrlg522z237w58tjn2rm00000gp/T/gomobile-work-931510225 golang.org/x/mobile/example/bind/hello failed: exec: "gobind": executable file not found in $PATH

I already tried to specified path inside class `GobindExtension` in `GobindPlugin.groovy` as per below:

```
class GobindExtension {
    // Package to bind. Separate multiple packages with spaces. (required)
    def String pkg = "golang.org/x/mobile/example/bind/hello"

    // GOPATH: necessary for gomobile tool. (required)
    def String GOPATH = System.getenv("GOPATH")

    // GO: path to go tool. (can omit if 'go' is in the paths visible by Android Studio)
    def String GO = "/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin"

    // GOMOBILE: path to gomobile binary. (can omit if 'gomobile' is under GOPATH)
    def String GOMOBILE = "/Users/vierdamila1/Desktop/go-workspace/bin/gomobile"
}
```

And this is my GOPATH :

> export GOPATH="/Users/vierdamila1/Desktop/go-workspace"

But still not working. Did I missed something here? Really appreciate for any kind help.

Comment: Is your `bind` package within your `GOPATH`? And you should install the `bind` package to generate an executable file using `go install` and the location of this executable file will be basically at `$GOPATH/bin/`. Use that executable and can you try again?

Comment: Hi Bharath, thanks for your reply but sorry I don't understand what bind package that are you talking about? is it this package : /Users/vierdamila1/Desktop/go-workspace/src/golang.org/x/mobile/bind

Comment: or this package : /Users/vierdamila1/Desktop/go-workspace/src/golang.org/x/mobile/example/bind

Comment: Refer to [this link](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind) for actual pakage and [this link](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile) for installation of `go mobile`. You've to perform all those instructions from within your `$GOPATH`.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the solution, I put here for someone who might need the answer.
Actually the error is showing up because I haven't install gobind. So before you do gomobile bind, don't forget to install gobind by run below command :

> go install golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind

after that call the bind command :

> gomobile bind -target=android golang.org/x/mobile/example/bind/hello

The bind command will generate hello.aar file and you can put it inside your Android project libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. gobind package install

   `$ go get golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind`
2. init

   `$ gomobile init`
3. build

   `$ gomobile <build or bind> ...`